# Organize model and collection in backbone

Tags: json, backbone.js

I have a JSON response with the following structure:

```
{
    id: 1,
    status: 0,
    created_at: "Y:m:d H:m:s",
    updated_at "Y:m:d H:m:s)",
    order_items: [items]
}
```

Could I make a collection with it? The ID, status etc. are just metadata. Or should I create  new `ItemsCollection` for the items array? Also will I get notified when an item changed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you're on the right track. You simply have to define three things:

1. A `Model` for your `order` object
2. A `Model` for the `order_item` object
3. A `Collection` for `order_item`s

Remember that every `Model` is responsible for its own validation, so you need to write a validate function for it.

Then, every time you parse your JSON, in your item's `parse` method, you need to convert the `order_item`s to a backbone `Collection` using something like:

```
parse: function(response) {
    if (!_.isNull(response) && !_.isNull(response.orderitems)) {
        response.orderitems = new OrderItems(response.orderitems);
    }
    return response;        
}
```

Once you've done this, everything should work as-intended!

Comment: The events from the models in the collection will most likely not bubble up to the containing order model unless you specifically wire them up.  This is because the OrderItems collection will not hit the "set" event on the model.

You could add a line after the line in which you new it up that would bridge the events.  this.listenTo(response.orderitems, "all", function(ev) { //bridge it to the model });

Answer (score 3):

you can do all of that, but you have to do it yourself or with a plugin. chances are, the code you end up writing will be similar to what's available in the Backbone.Relational plugin:

http://github.com/PaulUithol/Backbone-relational

i recommend using that plugin instead of rolling the code yourself

Answer (score 3):

As described in Backbone (http://backbonejs.org/#FAQ-nested) you should use the following way...

Edit: You do not need any plugins. Futhermore I do not recommend this, as with Backbone you can be sure you have a rock-solid framework, but they do not check how rock-solid is any plugin they propagate on their website. I had many projects where I had to think about nesting. In the end, the here shown way was the most secure and the most conventional.

### Strucutre

```
var Order = Backbone.Model.extend({
   initialize : function(data) {
      this.orderItems = new OrderItems(null, {order:this});
      if (!!data.order_items) {
          this.orderItems.reset(data.order_items, {parse:true});
          //we dont want nesting in "attributes"
          this.unset("order_items");
      }
   },
   // this is used, when a change from server happens. So when
   // the model already exists, and the stuff in initialize
   // wouldnt be called anymore.
   parse : function(data) {
       if (!!data.order_items) {
           this.orderItems.reset(data.order_items);
           delete data.order_items;
       }
       return data;
   }
});

var Orders = Backbone.Collection.extend({
   model : Order
});

var OrderItem = Backbone.Model.extend({

});

var OrderItems = Backbone.Collection.extend({
   model : OrderItem,
   initialize : function(data, options) {
      if (options && options.order) {
          this.order = options.order;
      } 
   }
};
```

### Binding

```
myOrder.orderItems.on("...");

myOrder.on("...");
```

### Access

access your Order from within the OrderItems.

```
var someOrderItem = myOrders.get(1).orderItems.first();
someOrderItem.collection.order === myOrders.get(1)
// will result in "true"
```

### Lazy loading

sometimes we dont want to load everything in one request. Most of the time I prefer to load the base collection, and only when a view does load one model, and the model has subcollections, I retrieve them later. For this I have a fetchOnce method.

```
var OrderItems = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize : function() {
        if (options && options.order) {
           this.order = options.order;
        }
        this.fetchOnce = _.once(this.fetch, this);
        //this will always return you an jquery xhr deferred.
    },
    url : function() {
        if (this.order) {
           // url() would return you something like "/order/1234"
           return this.order.url() + "/items"
        }
    }
);
```

Then somewhere else, you would initialize and fetch your complete orders.

```
   var orders = new Orders();
   orders.fetch();
```

if you then do some edit view and want all order items to be present too, you would do following.

```
   var view = new Backbone.View({
      order : orders.get(1)
   });

   view.order.orderItems.fetchOnce().done(function() {
       view.render();
   });
```

as fetchOnce returns a new deferred if not existant, or an existing (because of _.once) you can always bind to it, if it was called already previously, you will be notified in the done too...

Answer (score 0):

You could also define it dynamically:

```
var Order = Backbone.Model.extend({
   initialize: function () {
      this.getItems = _.memoize(this.getItems); // not necessary, but improves performance
   },
   getItems: function () {
     var that = this; 
     var col = new Backbone.Collection(this.get('order_items'));
     col.on('change', function() {
                          that.set({order_items: this.toJSON()});
                      });
     return col;
   }
})
```

Any change to the returned collection would automatically update the parent model.  Note: the parent model can only listen for changes to 'order_items' not it's children.

Comment: so every time you call getItems a new collection is made, and everytime you bind a callback to it, so even if you then do a new one, you do not remove the callback from the previous? I think you have a good chance to run into memory leaks

Comment: memoize in the init function.  eliminates multiple calls.

But in any event there is no memory leak.  The collection is, in effect, watching it's self.  Once released it will self dispose.  It's reference to the Model instance will retain the instance until all collections have been disposed of.

Comment: so you wouldnt prefer my method where I say that every Order has its OrderItems by default? I dont see any benefits here.

Comment: Depends on if he wants to retain the top level model data.  I have a few cases myself where my models are hierarchical, and this does the trick.  Yours is simpler, if the data being passed back is JUST a collection, and the meta data might handle things like validation or paging. (which I personally would rather put in the http header)